# Debezium PostgreSQL Connector table.include.list not updated when config changes

Tags: postgresql, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, debezium

I have an issue with updating table.include.list in my connector.
When I initially run my connector everything works okay. I have 2 psql tables in public schema: cn_oder, dbz_signal.

```
curl -i -X POST -H "Content-Type:application/json" \
    http://localhost:8083/connectors \
    -d ' {
    "name": "inventory-connector",
    "config": {
        "connector.class": "io.debezium.connector.postgresql.PostgresConnector",
        "tasks.max": "1",
        "database.hostname": "XXX.internal",
        "database.port": "5434",
        "database.user": "debezium_user",
        "database.password": "passwordXXX",
        "database.dbname" : "cn_db",
        "database.server.name": "myinstance",
        "schema.include": "public",
        "table.include.list": "public.cn_order,public.dbz_signal",
        "signal.data.collection": "public.dbz_signal",
        "plugin.name":"pgoutput",
        "publication.autocreate.mode":"filtered",
    }
}'
```

Then I add a new table (with the same privileges, owernship as cn_order) cn_user
However, after adding this table **public.cn_user** to table.include.list so it becomes `"table.include.list": "public.cn_order,public.cn_user,public.dbz_signal"`
and send the connector config update request

```
curl -i -X PUT -H "Accept:application/json" -H  "Content-Type:application/json" \
    http://localhost:8083/connectors/inventory-connector/config \
    -d '{...the same as the config before only table.include.list updated as mentioned above...}'
```

my consumer topic myinstance.public.cn_user doesn't get any streaming data, when I insert the rows to public.cn_user

However, the my consumer topic gets the past data, if I send a snapshot signal

```
sql = "INSERT INTO public.dbz_signal VALUES ('signal-1', 'execute-snapshot', '{\"data-collections\": [\"public.cn_user\"]}')"
```

but no streaming data...

Did anyone experience this before? Any advice is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I am facing the same issue. Were you able to figure out the issue?

Comment: did either find the soluiton? @JDev